# Executing JavaScript code from React Native Android native land

Tags: javascript, android, broadcastreceiver, react-native

Say I have a listener for specific events in Android, for example, a BroadcastReceiver that listens to wifi state changes. How would I start JavaScript code from this native context?

I would like to implement the logic for handling that broadcast in JavaScript, but reading the React Native documentation, I couldn't find a way to spin up JavaScript from Androids' Java code.

Comment: I'm sure you've found your answer by now, but for anyone else who finds this, look here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/705daabbb1fa8725e20e4fea0ec7174d5fc6aebc/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/netinfo/NetInfoModule.java

The example given in the react-native docs didn't help me at all with my broadcast receiver. I scoured RN's codebase for an example of an event that fires in JS when a broadcast receiver receives an intent. NetInfoModule  covers it all!

Comment: @MicronXD that's amazing. I did not find an answer, and I tried a workaround, so I love that you actually have figured it out! I'm going to review that file thoroughly this weekend. Thank you for letting me know :)

Answer (score -1):

You can add a listener in JavaScript and send an Event from native code. You can find an example in docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript).

Comment: Does that work from a background action like a BroadcastReceiver, where I might not necessarily have a ReactContext available?